# Spring Roo fails to generate Finder when setter declares throws

Tags: spring-roo

Had Roo generate a finder `findInterviewsByInterviewState`, no problem.

Then I modified the setter on `interviewState` to throw an exception:

```
   public void setInterviewState(InterviewState nextState) throws IllegalStateTransitionException{ 
         this.interviewState = this.interviewState.transitionTo(nextState, this);
   }
```

Roo then deleted `findInterviewsByInterviewState` and I had to rewrite it by hand.

Bug or feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a bug. Could you create a issue on [Spring-Roo Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO/)?

Include Spring-Roo version and, if you can, a backup of a little proof of concept to reproduce it.

Thank you.